# How do I display only weather info in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, weather

The weather card in the taskbar is pretty useful but I don't care about the news articles it keeps showing me, is there a way to only see the weather or important info?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge with Windows 10 and 11 the Weather Icon is All or Nothing.  I turned mine off because of this "feature"

Answer (score 0):

I have done some research on this issue.

In Windows 10, you can adjust interests, but it is fairly detailed and painful accordingly.

On the news app in the Weather App, click on the right arrow ( > ) in the title bar.  In the dialogue box that comes up (Edge page), click on Personalize (Icon near top right), and personalize what you do not want to see.

Fairly detailed and there is no option for: "Nothing but Weather".

Best to take an All or Nothing approach. I turn this icon off and use Weather on my iPhone.  The line of least resistance.